# HEX Code in Color Chooser for Mavericks?

Tags: macos, color

How can I get a HEX code entry into the Color Chooser for Mavericks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the [**Hex Color Picker**](http://wafflesoftware.net/hexpicker/):

[image: #123456][image: #AABBCC]

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16717/how-can-i-find-color-codes-on-mac and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18353/how-can-i-get-the-hexadecimal-functionality-of-digital-colormeter-back

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a custom picker

Comment: This is a plugin for the standard color picker. Unfortunately, it does not work for me. For some reason the hex picker returns wrong hex values. E.g. a full red image (#ff000000) created in photoshop, is evaluated as #f70016. See a screenshot here: http://o7.no/1mQpv4Z

Comment: Those differences are due to your display color profile. Nothing to do with the app. The photoshop color is just converted through your display colorprofile into a value that is shown on the screen. If you pick it you get the converted color.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Palette Tab.

Change the selection to 'Web Safe Colors'

[image]

This will give you:

[image]

---

Update :

I made a quick app so I could create a custom HEX picker palette using the colours found at [http://www.w3schools.com's html_colornames](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp)

---

UPDATE:
I found a list at :  [http://www.colourlovers.com ultimate-html-color-hex-code-list](http://www.colourlovers.com/web/blog/2007/06/30/ultimate-html-color-hex-code-list)
I Combined the two lists : The process I use automaticlly removes repeats.
The Palette now holds about 1520 HEX Colors.

---

You can down load the .clr file [here](http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/download/1120/).

Place the file inside of you home **Colors** folder:
`~/Library/Colors/`

Some apps may need to be relaunched before their colour picker picks it up.
The New Picker can be found in the Palettes drop down menu.

[image][image]

If I get time I will also put on my blog the App. But I would need to change it a bit so it can be used to add any set of HEX codes. Or if any one knows where the is the ultimate HEX code list. I will try and convert that.

Comment: Can I type a HEX code into this?  I couldn't figure out how to.

Comment: You can use the search field at the bottom

Comment: The standard Web Safe Colours seemed to be fixed

Comment: New Update : The list I created now holds 1520 Hex Colours

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer, that app seems to be abandoned...